# SQL join to Java Criteria API

Tags: jpa, criteria, criteria-api

How can I write this SQL join in CriteriaQuery? There aren't relationship between the entities.

```
from 
Table_A a
  left join Table_B b on b.B_id = a.B_id
  left join Table_C c on c.C_id = a.column_x
  left join Table_C d on d.C_id = a.column_y
  left join Table_K k on k.K_id = a.column_z
  left join Table_F f on f.F_id = a.column_t
  left join Table_V v on v.V_id = a.column_t
                              and v.col_s <= b.col_w
                              and v.col_g >= b.col_w
```

Something like this:

```
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<A> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(getClazz());
    Root<A> root = criteriaQuery.from(getClazz());

    Join<B, A> join = root.join(B_.ID)
                           .join(C_.ID);

    CriteriaQuery<A> query = criteriaQuery.select(join);
```

But I can not determine which column should match.

```
        .join(C_.ID == A_.X) 
        .join(K_.ID == A_.Z) 
        
        .join(V_.ID == A_.t && 
                V_.S <= B_.W && 
                V_.G >= B_.W
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are no relationships between the entities, for CriteriaAPI you will have to model the query as if they were all root tables, and the conditions in the where clause as follows:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<A> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(A.class);

Root<A> rootA = criteriaQuery.from(A.class);
Root<B> rootB = criteriaQuery.from(B.class);
Root<C> rootC1 = criteriaQuery.from(C.class);
Root<C> rootC2 = criteriaQuery.from(C.class);
Root<K> rootK = criteriaQuery.from(K.class);
Root<F> rootF = criteriaQuery.from(F.class);
Root<V> rootV = criteriaQuery.from(V.class);

List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootA.get(A_.bId),rootB.get(B_.bId)));
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootA.get(A_.columnX),rootC1.get(C_.cId)));
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootA.get(A_.columnY),rootC2.get(C_.cId)));
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootA.get(A_.columnZ),rootK.get(K_.kId)));
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootA.get(A_.columnT),rootF.get(K_.fId)));

predicates.add(
    criteriaBuilder.and(
        criteriaBuilder.equal(rootA.get(A_.columnT),rootV.get(V_.vId)),
        criteriaBuilder.and(
            criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(rootV.get(V_.colS),rootB.get(B_.colW)),
            criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(rootV.get(V_.colG),rootB.get(B_.colW))
         )
     )
 );

criteriaQuery.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
```

Although my recommendation is that you model the relationships in the entities, since this makes N Cartesian products being N the number of Roots, something that is very less optimal